# Black screen after boot Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot, nvidia, 20.04, screen, boot-repair

I installed in a new computer Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10, which I installed first, both in UEFI mode. During the installation of Ubuntu from the live USB I had to run the setup in "secure graphics" mode because the normal one didn't start and the screen remained black.

Now when I try to start Ubuntu from the GNU GRUB menu I always get stuck in the black screen problem. I have tried several options regarding this problem without success, among them:

1. Change Ubuntu commands with "e" and add **nomodeset** in the parameters of Linux command, or **nouveau.modeset=0**, **acpi = off** or **nolapic**
2. Disable secure boot mode from BIOS

These are my PC specs:
Motherboard: ASUS TUFGaming X570
CPU: AMD Ryzen 3900x
GPU: MSI Nvidia 2080 Super